# Two 12.04 versions on one machine. Cant access data

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04. Shame on me, but I too late noticed that my powercord was out of machine and as a result of that in the upgrading process my laptop switched of. When turned on it shows black screen with icons, but no possibility to move mouse or do anything else. I made bootable USB stick with 12.04 version. It took a long time to split(?) HD and install it. It looks like itš working fine, but the thing is that I cant access my files and folders - every thing is just empty. So the question is

- how can I get my files back
- there are two Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine,
  but when I switched on there is a list of options to choose, but
  starts one version of them with no files. Is there a way to get
  my files back?

Answer (score 1):

If you have formatted the partition that contained your data, then you will have to use a recovery tool to get back the files. You can use testdisk (`sudo apt-get install testdisk`) which I have personally found to be quite effective.

Or else, if you have just mounted/booted-into the 12.04 that has the home folder that contains no data, you can simply locate the other partition with `sudo fdisk -l` , mount it and copy/get your data from there

Comment: I have to try it on "empty" version of 12.04 I presume?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Try what on "empty" version? I'd recommend you download Gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted), open the application and take a screen shot of it and update your question with it.

Comment: Shame on me again, but how can I add a screen shot here?

Comment: Shame on me again, but how can I add a screen shot here? Gparded shows that I have two partitions - /dev/sda1 used space is 77Gb (there is data that I need) and /dev/sda2 wich splits in /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6. sda2 is "extended", sda6 is "ext4" and mount point "/", sda5 is "linux-swap". All of them (sda2, sda5, sda) have "key symbol"..... So any advice for dummy :)

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000437ba

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   565297308   282647630+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       565299198   976771071   205735937    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       968689664   976771071     4040704   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       565299200   968689663   201695232   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Comment: Last two comments is what I get when running "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: If it helps anyone - when started my machine I choose some older version (?) which was saved on "sda1" and it was old 11.10 environment with all my files and folders, but with no access to web. So I am going to save the files on external HD and then copy them to 12.04 version. Hope it will work. But still - I think this is not the normal way how it should be and I would be very thankful if anyone could comment this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Mount the old partition to /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

# See if the files are there (assuming the username is the same on both installations)
ls -l /mnt/home/$USER/

# Create dir for back-up and copy all the files from the old /home
mkdir /home/$USER/recov && cp -R /mnt/home/$USER/* /home/$USER/recov/
```

If it gets mounted as Read Only, try; `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /mnt`

## Encrypted home

If you've encrypted your home directory on the old installation, it'll get tricky.

In that case, try the following:

```
# After mounting
chroot /mnt

# Switch user
su <username>
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

You can find a copy of your files at the given location.

If that doesnt work, try; `ecryptfs-recover-private`

If that doesnt work either, you're done.. and lost...